# How To Call A String Resource In C++

Tags: string, visual-c++, resources

in resource.h

```
#define String1 333
```

in resource.rc

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

STRINGTABLE
{
    STRING1                   "hie people"
}
```

in main.cpp

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<resource.h>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main{
cout<<here i want to output string value from resource how to call the string;
}
```

and one more problem i am compiling in code blocks .it says resource.h is not there where i am wrong

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev thank you

Comment: Please tag this with VC++ or whatever tools you're using - it's got nothing to do with C (as per existing tag) nor C++ (as per title) per se.

Comment: okay i will take care next time..actually i was not aware as i am new on so

Comment: it's not a problem - just helps people with relevant knowledge focus in on you, and others filter you out ;-).  Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that it is Visual C++ and you are using MFC. It is as simple as calling:

```
::LoadString(...)
```

And if you are using MFC, then

```
CString str;
str.LoadString(STRING1)
```

[LoadString from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[An Example here of how to use LoadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#creating_child)

Comment: @Dapu, then use the first version. You will have to provide arguments. I have added the link as well